# Doctrine2 - Only update entities that have changed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony, I must display a form that can have up to 800+ fields, all of them checkboxes, in order to tally attendance for a given month. I am well aware that, if I send the form and perform an update, I will have well over 800 update statements alone (not counting any possible inserts), and this is undesirable as it might perform poorly in terms of memory and time.

I know Doctrine can manage Lifecycle Callbacks, however I'm unexperienced on them and I believe the solution is here. How do I unmark an entity for merge if its value has not changed?

Comment: Just a thought.. this seems like something a raw query should do or change the dynamics of the page to an ajax request per check-box?

Comment: I considered that too, but if it was possible to do what I'm asking, then I'd be able to keep it simple (javascript is an extra layer of complexity). A raw query is a good solution though but I still need to keep track of the updated entities or else the query string might be needlessly long.

Comment: D2 has several strategies for avoiding unnecessary updates.  The default one will probably work just fine  so I would suggest doing some testing before worrying about it.  However, implementing the Change Notification strategy will solve the issue.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html

Comment: That's perfect! Post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently and it helped me with a similar situation. What you will want to use is doctrine entity managers transactional function. Something like:

```
//Controller Action
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType);
if($request->isMethod('post')){
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $data = $form->getNormData();
        //If you have some other way of getting all your data use that

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->transactional(function($em) use($data){
            foreach($data as $user){
                $attendance = new Attendance(new \DateTime);
                //Total assumption on how you handle attendance
                $user->addAttendance($attendance);
                $em->flush();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This will lump all of your updates into a single transaction and will also handle reverting if it fails.

For more info take a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Comment: Transactions are neat but they don't solve my issue. You can place within a transaction hundreds of operations, commit, and you will still be doing the hundreds of operations. My question is about **reducing the amount of update queries to the database only for the values that actually change**.

Comment: Aw I miss understood what exactly you were looking for. It was also my understanding that doctrine already handled only using update queries for objects that have been changed. So if you only modify the ones that you need to instead of using the form to update ALL of them wouldnt this solve your concern?

Comment: One of the comments in my question already solves the issue. I wasn't aware there was a way to shift the tracking policy from implicit to explicit.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved :D Sorry my answer wasn't what you were looking for.